# Could not run Grails project GGTS

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a grails project that runs perfectly in the command line. When I try to run it in GGTS with

```
grails run-app
```

it runs the first time without any error. Then, I stopped the server and ran it again with grails run-app. Now the following errors occur.

```
| Error 2013-04-29 15:32:14,965 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'annotationHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JacksonAnnotation
Message: Error creating bean with name 'annotationHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JacksonAnnotation
Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JacksonAnnotation
->> 3098 | initAnnotationsIfNecessary in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   3057 | getAnnotation in     ''
|   3070 | isAnnotationPresent in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JacksonAnnotation
->>  175 | findClass in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    423 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    147 | loadClass in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
|    356 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   3098 | initAnnotationsIfNecessary in java.lang.Class
|   3057 | getAnnotation in     ''
|   3070 | isAnnotationPresent in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I also tried to delete .grails/2.2.1/projects/MyProject directory and updated the dependencies. Refresh dependencies works fine but run-app does not work in GGTS.
What should I do?

Comment: For Grails 2.2.1 you need the latest GGTS, 3.2 if I'm not mistaken. Is this your version?

Comment: yes I am using GGTS 3.3M1 with Grails 2.2.2 now. It works but when you delete .grails/2.2.2/MyProject it also gives the error above. What should I do?

Comment: Why are you deleting the .grails folder?  Does running grails compile work?

Comment: I deleted the folder because of the conflicts. Rrun compile does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, try the following in this order

```
grails clean
grails refresh-dependencies
grails run-app
```

If it still doesn't work, you may want to delete your *.grails/2.2.2/projects/** and repeat the above-mentioned steps.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the problem is caused by the Java 7 version. Do not user Update 21 then the error will vanish.

Comment: doesn't work, currently using jdk1.7.0_17.jdk and it still happens

Comment: try to delete .grails/version/project/yourprojectfolder then grails grefresh-dependencies

Comment: Ya the workaround works fine, however trying to get a working solution