# grails annotation error, not sure on solution, have workaround

Tags: grails

Currently have a fresh project for grails 2.2.1 and I get this error:

```
| Error 2013-08-14 15:31:26,358 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'annotationHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JacksonAnnotation
Message: Error creating bean with name 'annotationHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JacksonAnnotation
Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JacksonAnnotation
->> 3098 | initAnnotationsIfNecessary in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   3057 | getAnnotation in     ''
|   3070 | isAnnotationPresent in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JacksonAnnotation
->>  175 | findClass in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    423 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    147 | loadClass in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
|    356 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   3098 | initAnnotationsIfNecessary in java.lang.Class
|   3057 | getAnnotation in     ''
|   3070 | isAnnotationPresent in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I have a workaround of

```
grails clean
grails refresh-dependencies
grails run-app
```

This works until I need to restart my grails app.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16386851/2051952).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this problem stems from Java 7 (I have uodate 17).  I turned it back to Java 6 and was fine.